# How to find previously pressed key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to find what key was pressed previously using Javascript using approach which is cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Which browser does `onkeypress` not work in? Or am I missing what you are askin g?

Comment: Thats good, what was the question?

Comment: @doctorlove lets say i pressed key 'A' and then 'B', i want to check what was pressed before 'B' , in this case its 'A'

Comment: It would be great if people downvoting post proper reason while downvote

Comment: You'd need to use `onkeypress` and store the key presses somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a solution like this.

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
    Just start typing here ... 
</textarea>

<p>
    This is the previously pressed key: <span id="output"> </span>
</p>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
var pressedKeys = [];
var lastKey;

$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
    pressedKeys.push(e.key);
    lastKey = pressedKeys[pressedKeys.length - 2]

    $('#output').html(lastKey);
});
```

Watch it on CodePen here: http://codepen.io/MarkBuskbjerg/pen/Yppbrg

Answer (score 1):

This isn't information that the browser tracks automatically. You have to do it yourself.

When a keypress event fires, compare the keycode to the value stored in a variable. Then store the new keycode in that variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastKeyCode;
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e){
 console.log('lastKeyCode', lastKeyCode);
 var nowKeyCode = e.keyCode;
 console.log('nowKeyCode', nowKeyCode);
 lastKeyCode = nowKeyCode;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your own keypress log in an array like this:

```js
var logKeyPress = [];

document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e){ 
 logKeyPress.push(e.key); 
 document.body.innerHTML = `<p>${logKeyPress.toString()}</p><p>previous Key is: ${logKeyPress[logKeyPress.length-2]}`;
})

document.body.innerText = "Click and Press me";
```